# MIPS - Accessing data stored in an array

Tags: arrays, mips

I have been using StackOverflow for a while to help with homework, but I couldn't find an answer this time.

I thought I had everything working, but when I changed the elements in the array it didn't do anything.

In my program I have to initialize the array, print out the array, then call a method to sum the elements in the array. I have to pass two parameters, one being the base address of the array, and the other being the length of the array.

This is my code as of now. It is just printing out 1 through the length, and ignoring what is actually in the array.

```
.data
array: .word 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
newline:.asciiz "\n"
space:  .asciiz " "
.text

la   $a0, array     # $a0 -----> array
li   $a1, 5     # $a1 -----> length of array

jal SUM         # calls sum
j end
SUM:  
    move $t0, $a0       # $t0 -----> $a0 ( array )
    move $t1, $a1       # $t1 -----> $a1 ( length of array )
    li   $t2, 0     # $t2 -----> 0 ( i = 0 )
    li   $t3, 0     # $t3 -----> 0 ( sum = 0 )
loop:
    beq  $t1, $t2, endloop  # checks to see if length of array == i

    mul  $t4, $t2, 4    # multiply i by 4, so offset stays with array in loop
    add  $t4, $t0, $t4  # puts memory address of array into $t3 so we get array [i]
    sw   $t4, ($t4)     # loads memory address of array[i] into $t3
    addi $t2, $t2, 1    # i++;

    add  $t3, $t3, $t2  # sum = sum + array [i];

    li   $v0, 1     # prints value
    move $a0, $t2       # at
    syscall         # array[i]

    li   $v0, 4     # prints 
    la   $a0, space     # a
    syscall             # space

    j loop

endloop:
    li   $v0, 4     # prints
    la   $a0, newline   # a
    syscall         # new line

    li   $v0, 1        # prints value
    add  $a0, $t3, $0   # of
    syscall              # sum

    jr $ra
end:
```

sorry for the formatting of the comments, I couldn't figure out how to align them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several errors:

```
sw   $t4, ($t4)     # loads memory address of array[i] into $t3
```

This doesn't match the comment. Also you shouldn't load the value into $t3 because you would overwrite the sum (`# $t3 -----> 0 ( sum = 0 )`). I would use $t5, so it should be like:

```
lw   $t5, ($t4)
```

---

Also you're adding the index to the sum instead of the actual array value:

```
add  $t3, $t3, $t2
```

With the previous correction using LW, it should be:

```
add  $t3, $t3, $t5
```

---

And finally you're printing the indexes instead of the values as well:

```
move $a0, $t2
```

Should be

```
move $a0, $t5
```

PS: use branch to loop, not jump. Jump is usually used for function calls or far calls.

PS2: to end your program use syscall 10.

PS3: also you should read about [MIPS delay slot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_slot).

Comment: oops, sorry. i just forgot to update my comment. it should $t4 instead of $t3

Comment: or is this the part of the code that i am messing up at? if so, how would i fix it?

Comment: I've expanded my answer

Comment: After changing all of the mistakes you pointed out, it prints all 0s.